# How can I SUM alphanumeric values in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

It's not the best system but I've been using ImportXML to pull in YouTube view counts for my videos so I can keep track. I knew at some point YouTube would make a front end change that would break this. So now recently instead of just the number inside of the DIV I am referencing they are always showing the word "views". So here's what I'm using now

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXnr03IIPTI","//div[@class='watch-view-count']")
```

This will output "300,000 views" (or whatever the current view count is)

Before they added the word "views" in this DIV I was able to add up this column. So I added another column to strip out the text.

(where G7 is the cell containing the above value)

```
=SUBSTITUTE(G7, "views", "")
```

I thought for sure I would then be able to run a SUM on this column but alas the SUM is 0. I believe this is something Excel would be able to deal with.

Any ideas here?

Bonus points if you watch the video :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result is in G7, use formula:

```
=JOIN("",REGEXEXTRACT(G7,"([0-9]+),([0-9]+),?([0-9]+)?"))*1
```

it will convert string "300,000 views" into number. It'll handle bigger numbers, like: 1,368,142 views. This formula replaces commas because in some countries comma is used as sepatator integer and decimal part of number.

Comment: Thanks, this is prefect! I think the key for Sheets to recognize the output as a number so the "*1" helps. I like Aurielle's solution as well. These are both great but I like how you added the Regex for the commas and decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a value:

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXnr03IIPTI","//div[@class='watch-view-count']")," views",""))
```

or

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXnr03IIPTI","//div[@class='watch-view-count']"),"[, views]",""))
```

if you really want the commas etc, wrap the final amount back into a text at the very end if you want such as `=TEXT("FINAL SUM","#,#")`

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! I was unaware of "VALUE" and that this would make the SUM work. I had a tough time awarding the 'correct' answer so I gave the solution to Max because he added in a RegEx for the commas. Don't hate me! :) Thanks!!

Comment: I could have added the commas, didnt know you wanted them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXnr03IIPTI","//div[@class='watch-view-count']"), "[0-9]*\,[0-9]+[0-9]+")
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Somehow Sheets doesn't like to SUM the output of this. As you can see from the other responses they solutions either "*1" at the end or use "VALUE" which both resolve my issue. Thanks though!